# Update Contact email from custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

This is the error

> Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete
>   SObject: List at line 15 column 18

**line 15 was:**
con1.email = prenew.Changed_Email__c;

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {
List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNew = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >(); 

SET <Id> newset = new SET <Id>();


    for(Public_Register_Employee__c pre : Trigger.new){
        newset.add(pre.id__c);   
        preNew.add(pre);  
        }

    for(Contact con1 :[Select Id, email, name, sss_no__c FROM Contact Where Id =: newset]){
    system.assertEquals(con1+'','test');
    con1.ESS_User__c = true;
    con1.email = prenew.Changed_Email__c;
    }


}
```

Comment: here `prenew` is list you need to use like `prenew[0]` for first record.. or create a map with `pre.id__c` and `Public_Register_Employee__c` then use that map in another loop

Comment: is there any way without using map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using map just store contactId to Public Register employee record

check below code and try to understand..

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {

    // map to hold the contactId to Public Register employee record
    map<Id, Public_Register_Employee__c> mapContactIdToPublicRegisterEmp = new map<Id, Public_Register_Employee__c>();

    for(Public_Register_Employee__c pre : Trigger.new){
        mapContactIdToPublicRegisterEmp.put(pre.id__c, pre);
    }
    List<contact> lstContact = [Select Id, email, name, sss_no__c 
                        FROM Contact 
                       Where Id IN: mapContactIdToPublicRegisterEmp.keySet()];
    for(Contact con1 :lstContact){
    con1.ESS_User__c = true;
    //based on contact Id get the Public Register employee record's changed email value
    con1.email = mapContactIdToPublicRegisterEmp.get(con1.Id).Changed_Email__c;
    }
    update lstContact;
}
```